# Tomcat7 deploy class files formerly deployed by invoker servlet

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

I am migrating a lot of Servlets that has previously been deployed by the invoker servlet to a new tomcat7 installation. I understand that I must create servlet and servlet-mapping elements in web.xml to get it to work, but I don't get it to work.
I started by making all my old servlet classes that was in the default package now be in a package called servlets.
The ROOT-folder in tomcat7 didn't have a WEB-INF folder allready, so I created this, and created a new web.xml-file in this folder, that looks like this at the moment (with just 1 servlet to start with, and web-apps element copied from etc/tomcat7/web.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ScannerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.ScannerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ScannerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I then placed all my class files in ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\servlets
I then restarted tomcat and tried http://myip.com:8080/servlet/ScannerServlet but I then get the "The requested resource is not available.
I then tried adding the servlet and servlet-mapping to etc/tomcat7/web.xml but with no futher success.
What have I done wrong? Or have I done it right, but there remains some things more to do?

[edit]
I have tried creating a new folder in ROOT, called servlet, and moving the WEB-INF folder here.
If I put an index.html-file in the servlet-folder, it will show up if I call http://myip.com:8080/servlet/ but I still get 'The requested resource is not available when trying to call ... /servlet/ScannerServlet or ... /servlet/servlet/ScannerServlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!
I moved my files and folders to webapps/servlet/ instead of webapps/ROOT/
Then I changed the url-pattern to /ScannerServlet
Then the servlet is accessible from http://myip.com:8080/servlet/ScannerServlet :-)